# Optimal strategy in modified guessing 2/3 of the average.

Tags: recreational-mathematics, game-theory, nash-equilibrium

In the original "Guessing 2/3 of the average" game, guessing 0 is said to be the optimal strategy assuming that everyone is rational.

In this modified version of this game, players can input 2 answers, the first answer being any integer from 0 to 100 while the other answer must be a positive integer from 50 to 100.

The goal is to have your first answer to be as close as possible to 2/3 of the average of all answers.

The lowest possible 2/3 of average is 50/3 and the highest possible average is still at 200/3.

If we attempt to follow the optimal strategy considered in the original game, then one should guess 17 for the first answer and 50 for the second answer.

However, if everyone follows this strategy, the average would be 67/3 instead and a higher first guess is better so this strategy is not optimal.

If this repeats, the optimal value for the first answer should be 25. I assume that this would be the most optimal strategy.

However, for any positive integer from 50 to 100 for the 2nd answer, there is a "optimal" strategy such that if everyone else also chooses that integer for the 2nd answer, the player has the highest chance of winning as well.

Does that mean there are multiple possible optimal strategies? I highly doubt so and hence I am trying to figure out which strategy is truly optimal.

(My choice of word for optimal may be used imprecisely so I apologize if I did use it in an incorrect manner.)

Comment: Could you make the layout easier to read for us? this is a big block of informations. Also if you have mathematical background, you could reformulate it with it?

Comment: I am afraid that I only do math recreationally, so I am not experienced in the formatting or formulating of information. I have tried to include spaces to help make reading slightly easier but please bear with this format for now.

Comment: Thanks you that is already better :)

Comment: Is this the game in Alice in borderland? This game highly depends on psychology, way more than math, taking $0$ is risky when you begin and when you have a lot of players but once they are scared to loose they will do the same

Comment: That's why they add a rule: if two people choose the same number they lose points

Comment: The original version of the game is indeed used in Alice in borderland but the origin of it dates back to quite some time ago in the late 1800s I believe. My modified version is original and self-made however.

Comment: When you say they are rational, does it means they choose randomly and independently ? or do they want to apply the best strategy and hence think like you

Comment: Rationality is one of the most common assumptions made in game theory. In its mildest form, rationality implies that every player is motivated by maximizing his own payoff. So basically, in this case, every player is attempting and using the optimal strategy or maximizing his utility to guess the integer closest to 2/3 of the average.

Comment: I think in this case it definitely matters what happens on a tie. Do the tied players get nothing? Do they win "just as much" as a solo win? Do they get a "fractional win" (if they were playing for money, divide the prize equally)?

Answer (score 0):

Ok what you seem to want looks like a fixed point theorem. Let us denote $x_0,y_0$ the "optimal inputs", everybody would logically input the same if they want to win.

The condition is then
$$\frac{2}{3}\frac{x_0+y_0}{2} = x_0$$
this gives you:
$$x_0 = \frac{y_0}{2}$$
So you have a lot of "possible optimal strategies" Let's say now that every player (other than you) chose randomly (and independently i.e. they don't form alliances) its $x$ and then just chooses $y = 2x$. He has an uniform choice for its $x$ to make in $\{0,\dots ,50\}$ so you could tell that the average choice would be $24,5$, hence you should choose $(24,50)$ or $(25,49)$ these are the closest you could get

Comment: The other players choosing a uniform random number doesn't match the requirement they're rational. They also want to win and will be smart about it.

Comment: Yes but this is the snake biting his own tail, the ultimate solution is for everyone to choose the same $(x,2x)$ you have to make a choice and knowing human nature, the choice would be the mean, so choosing the means works since if every one follows this rules they all win... The game is not interesting then